# How to use the Jackson object mapper with Java 17

Tags: json, serialization, reflection, jackson, deserialization

I'm trying to implement a logic that serializes and de-serializes a very complex legacy object. The object contains other complex objects inside of it that are spread through various other projects. There are even some JAXB1 objects that are generated from an xsd schemas and are part of the chain.

Right now there is already a working version that uses XStream and this worked for years. But since Java 17 there are issues because of the new restriction for using reflection on private fields from different modules. Exceptions like this started to appear ->
Module {A} does not 'opens {package}' to {B}". One of the things that bothers me is that all of these packages are from some third party libs and I even can't find any objects from them in the model chain.

So I started implementing a new serialization based on the Jackson databind API but right now I'm wondering is it going to solve the issues at all? Does Jackson also use reflection in case to serialize and de-serialize? What is the best way to configure the ObjectMapper and what should I change in the objects that I need to work with in case to make the reflection usage as low as possible?

Right now I've configure the ObjectMapper as:

```
objectMapper.disable(MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_CREATORS,
                     MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_FIELDS,
                     MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_GETTERS,
                     MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_IS_GETTERS);

objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);
```

and I'm annotating all fields that should be serialized with @JsonProperty but I'm not sure that this is going to help. Okay, I assume I must have getters and setters, but should I also annotate them? Does the annotation has something to do with the reflection usage at all?